# Underbraces in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following tikzpicture:

[image]

generated by:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={}]
\node [circle,draw] (z){$f$}
child {node [circle,draw] (g1) {$x_1$}}
child {[white] node [black] (g2) {$\dots$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g3) {$x_1$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g4) {$x_2$}}
child {[white] node [black] (g5) {$\dots$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g6) {$x_2$}}
child {[white] node [black] (g7) {$\dots$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g8) {$x_m$}}
child {[white] node [black] (g9) {$\dots$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g10) {$x_m$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Now I would like to add underbraces, as examplified by my (rather beautiful, if I might say so myself) paint drawing:

[image]

How would I go about doing that in tikz?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a decoration from the `decorations.pathreplacing` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={},decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=7}]
\node [circle,draw] (z){$f$}
child {node [circle,draw] (g1) {$x_1$}}
child {[white] node [black] (g2) {$\dots$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g3) {$x_1$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g4) {$x_2$}}
child {[white] node [black] (g5) {$\dots$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g6) {$x_2$}}
child {[white] node [black] (g7) {$\dots$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g8) {$x_m$}}
child {[white] node [black] (g9) {$\dots$}}
child {node [circle,draw] (g10) {$x_m$}};

\draw [decorate] ([yshift=-5mm]g1.west) --node[below=3mm]{$n_1$} ([yshift=-5mm]g3.east);
\draw [decorate] ([yshift=-5mm]g4.west) --node[below=3mm]{$n_2$} ([yshift=-5mm]g6.east);
\draw [decorate] ([yshift=-5mm]g8.west) --node[below=3mm]{$n_m$} ([yshift=-5mm]g10.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you increase the thickness of the underbrace? Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasDevine Same as any other path. `\draw [decorate, thick] ...`. Or `very thick`, `ultra thick` or `line width=1cm`.