# Underbrace in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

The answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287784/underbraces-in-tikz) give a way to draw an underbrace in Tikz. But I'd like to know if it is possible to draw underbrace using asymptote? Because there is no package in asymptote seems to be able to do this.

Comment: I guess you get more feedback if you provide an MWE. You can access LaTeX macros in asymptote, i.e. put an $\underbrace{\hspace*{xcm}}_{\dots}$ somewhere and rotate it if everything else fails.

Answer (score 10):

In fact a `brace` routine is available. It was created by Charles Staats, and it is in the documentation (see `Paths and Guides` subsection).
The syntax is `path brace(pair a, pair b, real amplitude=bracedefaultratio*length(b-a))`

The following code

```
  size(10cm);
  path p=brace((0,0), (1,1),.1); // real amplitude=bracedefaultratio*length(b-a));
  path q=brace((1,1), (0,0),.2);
  draw(p,blue+1bp);
  draw(q,red+2bp);
  draw(brace((1,0),(1,1)),black+2bp);
  draw(brace((0,1),(0,0)),1bp+dashed);
```

produces this picture

[image]